# Need RegEx to remove all alphabets from string

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to move all alphabets from string (A-Z) and (a-z)..everything including any kind of special character should remain intact. I tried @"[^\d]" but it only returns numbers in string.

```
String : asd!@# $%dfdf4545D jasjkd #(*)jdjd56

desired output : !@# $%4545 #(*)56
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just replace all undesired characters with an empty string sequence:

```
string filtered = Regex.Replace(input, "[A-Za-z]", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regular expression:

```
[^a-zA-Z]
```

This will match all non-english letters.